# Случайная строка длиной 256 символов на Basic

Tags: visual-basic

Только начал изучать Visua Basic. Как сгенерировать случайную строку длиной 256 символов? Очень сложно с делфи сообразить((( Надеюсь на вашу помощь...

Comment: А как это выглядело бы на делфи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
randomize timer

sdat$ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVUWXYZ123456789"
slen = len(sdat$)-1
sout = ""

for a=1 to 256
k=int(slen*rnd)+1
sout$ = sout$ + mid$(sdat$,k,1)
next a

print sout$
```

единственное с rnd мог напутать там где +1 главное чтобы значение было целое и попадало в деапазон 0 < k <= slen